# mod_rpaf behind an Amazon ELB

Tags: amazon-elb, mod-rpaf

I've got `mod_rpaf` installed to get the user's IP address from the `X-Forwarded-For` header in PHP, Apache logs, etc.

Unfortunately, it looks like I have to explicitly set which IPs that header will be respected from via the `RPAFproxy_ips` setting.

Given that ELBs don't have a static IP, how can I tell `mod_rpaf` to accept the header from any IP, or even any 10.* IP?

Comment: Have you tried entering the entire list of possible IP addresses in mod_rpaf's conf file?  My gut feeling is that this is bad and will cause excess latency but we won't know until we actually try.  For that matter, do you *know* the entire list of possible IP addresses?

Comment: Amazon EC2 has more than a million IPs, so no. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1252

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `mod_extract_forwarded` instead of `mod_rpaf` — it supports `MEFaccept all` (and if you use RHEL/CentOS/other-clone, the package is already in EPEL). One downside of `mod_extract_forwarded` is that the `X-Forwarded-For` and `Forwarded-For` header names are hardcoded and not configurable like in `mod_rpaf`.

There is no support for IP ranges even in `mod_extract_forwarded`, but you may configure a firewall to allow direct access to Apache only from some IP ranges, or check the `MEF_RPROXY_ADDR` environment variable in `mod_rewrite` rules.

---

After some more thinking about this I found a problem with this `mod_extract_forwarded` config — while `mod_rpaf` does not support chains of multiple proxies and takes just the last address from the `X-Forwarded-For` header, `mod_extract_forwarded` attempts to support this and uses the last address which does not belong to the trusted proxy list (so that if the request has passed through multiple trusted proxies, the actual client address will be used instead of the second-to-last proxy address).  Unfortunately, using `MEFaccept all` means that `mod_extract_forwarded` will trust all proxies, therefore if ELB proxies just append their data to the `X-Forwarded-For` header, and not replace it completely, clients could pass any spoofed IP by sending requests with their own `X-Forwarded-For` headers.

However, I have found yet another module to parse `X-Forwarded-For` headers.  Recent (unstable) Apache versions have the [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html) module, which apparently supports subnet masks for proxy addresses.  There is a [backport to Apache 2.2](http://people.apache.org/~wrowe/httpd-2.2-ports/mod_remoteip.c) and a [spec file for Fedora](http://jsteffan.fedorapeople.org/SPECS/mod_remoteip.spec); unfortunately, the [request to include package in Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=656483) is stalled.

Comment: `MEFaccept all` sounds good, will give that a try - no risk as Amazon's firewalls will take care of outside traffic.

Comment: See the updated answer — there is a problem with this config which would enable clients to pass arbitrary spoofed IPs via `X-Forwarded-For` headers.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm probably comfortable about that - I'm not really using this for security so much as log analysis and troubleshooting. Not much of a reason for someone to spoof.

Comment: Then you will probably see lots of 192.168.x.x and similar addresses in your logs from proxies out there, which would not be very useful.

Comment: There is a [solution just for logging](http://mike.marineau.org/blog/howto/2008-10-15-tip-day-log-tweek-apachesquid) which does not require any extra modules; note that [another suggested solution](http://blog.grahampoulter.com/2011/10/how-to-log-client-ip-from-apache-behind.html) would have the same problem as `mod_extract_forwarded` — using the first address from `X-Forwarded-For` instead of the last one. But this won't help PHP.

Comment: Do you know how often the IPs associated with the DNS name of the proxy listed in MEFaccept config? This would be relevant when using AWS ELB where the number of ips backed the the elb can change. I want to know if I need to restart httpd?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can, from a quick reading of the source.  You could hack up the code pretty easily to just accept any source (by neutering the check at line 163 that looks like `is_in_array(r->connection->remote_ip, cfg->proxy_ips) == 1`, but that seems like a security risk.

Is there some way you can ask Amazon what the load balancers you are behind are at runtime?  If so you could generate the config on the fly...

Comment: Unfortunately, the IP of an AWS ELB can change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that CloudFlare have created their own [Apache module](https://www.cloudflare.com/wiki/Log_Files#For_Apache_Users) for doing this sort of thing and it does support CIDR notation for ranges.

The IP addresses are hard-coded in the source code but since they provide the source code it's easy enough to add your own range in there.

A comment in the source code indicates that it was derived from [mod_remoteip.c](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_remoteip.html) which is available in [Apache 2.3](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache23) (or 2.5 depending on whether you look at the URL or the title of that page.).